# R: How do I filter a vector of logicals?

Tags: r

I have a vector of logicals. There are many values and only one is TRUE.

I tried

```
dat[TRUE]
which(dat == TRUE)
which(dat IS TRUE)
dat[dat == TRUE]
dat[dat IS TRUE]
```

How do you filter for just the values that are  true?

Comment: You can do `dat[dat]`

Comment: It returns logical(0)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You say only one value is true, but then you want to filters for value**s** that are true? Guess what? You will get a vector of TRUE values (or an empty logical vector if there is none). Hardly helpful. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: `dat <- c(T,F,T,T,F);dat[dat]` [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE

Comment: If `dat[dat]` doesn't work for you then either (a) you don't have any true values in `dat` or (b) `dat` isn't actually a vector of logicals. Check `class(dat)`, `which(dat)`, `any(dat)`, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a vector of logicals, I'm assuming you want to find the position of the true value. This should work.

```
> vec <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
> which(vec)
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- c(name1=T,name3=F,name3=T)
# If you want return values:
dat[which(dat)]
# If you want names of which value is true:
names(dat[which(dat)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an actual need to do what the OP asked for, because my vector was named and I wanted to know the *names* that were `TRUE`.

For anyone stumbling upon this, you can do that with the following:

```
Filter(function(x) x, dat) # assumes 'dat' is the logical vector
```

Comment: That looks like a long way to write `dat[dat]` to me. And if you just want the names, `names(dat)[dat]` or if you're concerned about `NA`s,  `names(dat)[which(dat)]`

Comment: @Gregor, in my particular use-case, it wasn't `dat`, but a large expression which I wrapped in the above.

Comment: More specifically...
`Filter(function(x) !x, attr(rfModel$m$terms, "dataClasses")[-1] == sapply(dat, class))`